# Build address book from existing mail?

Tags: email, thunderbird

I'm starting out with Thunderbird and am trying to find a way to populate my address book with email addresses from my Inbox. This seems like a reasonable need, but I can't find any add-ons or innate functionality that work. The few I found were all years old and deprecated.